# Is there a way to solve 3x3 convolution kernel when you are given input & output images?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
import scipy as ss

inimg=cv.imread(r"D:\Master Mathematics\Modern Numerical Method\Assignment\berries_small.jpg")
ouimg=cv.imread(r"D:\Master Mathematics\Modern Numerical Method\Assignment\berries_small_blur.jpg")

conv=np.zeros((3,3),dtype=int)
k=np.linalg.solve(inimg,ouimg)
```

the error code i received was:
**raise LinAlgError('Last 2 dimensions of the array must be square')**

**LinAlgError: Last 2 dimensions of the array must be square**

i am unable to find the 3x3 convolution kernel, and the code keep getting error.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely not.  No way.  With a PNG it would be hard enough, but you must remember that JPEGs are compressed.  The numbers you get from decompression are not exactly the same as the numbers that get compressed.